# simple ratio question

Tags: ratio

x = men , y = women

in some company there are 3x men than woman.
so I know that x=3y

our teacher tought us a rule which he called "give to the poor", in this case the poor is the women because they are less than man, so I gave them 3. but I think this rule doesnt apply in this situation:

x=company 1 , y = company 2

there are 2 building companias.
one company builds 1/3 from the apartments in the city, while the other company build 2/3 from the apartments in the city.

I tried 2/3x=y , but it know it's wrong, because for example there are 21 apartments, so
x=7 , y = 14

(2/3)*7 != 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one company builds 1/3 from the apartments in the city, while the other company build 2/3 from the apartments in the city then the second company builds twice as much as the first one. This can be expressed as:

```
y  = 2x
14 = 2*7
```

In your first example you not only gave a lot (3) to the poor but also gave little (1) to the rich, hence:

```
1*x = 3*y
```

You need to do the same for the companies. Give a lot (2/3) to the poor and little (1/3) to the rich. Then you have:

```
2/3*x = 1/3*y
```

When you solve it (by multiplying both sides by 3) you get:

```
2x = y
```